# change value on array if key match in another array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => company
    [1] => companyid
)

Array
(
    [company] => shops
)
```

And I want the first array to look like this.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => shops
        [1] => companyid
    )
```

I've tried alot of built in array functions but I couldn't get a grip on them.

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data` is your first array, `$replacement` is the second

```
foreach( $replacements as $key => $value ){
  $data_key = array_search( $key, $data );
  if( $data_key !== false ) $data[ $data_key ] = $value;
}
```

Comment: It worked! but there has to be a small flip between the $data and $key so it looks likes this: $data[ array_search( $key, $data )] = $value;

Comment: Yes, I still haven't learned this: http://www.phpdevblog.net/uploads/files/haystack-needle.pdf